# Apache Camel, Netty4 endpoint as client - memory leakage

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, apache-camel, netty

I'm quite new to Apache Camel and trying to bring some routes into action.
I have a TCP server which serves large JSON-Messages (up to ~30-50kB in size, where i do not have any control about the source size) that contain lots of measurement data which i want to process using certain additional routes that work fine.
I'm using camel 2.20 within spring-boot environment 1.5.7.
I faced the problem that if i commented out every other routes except the incoming reduced netty4 route (only from and to a counter), see below

```
@Bean
public RouteBuilder getRoute() {
    String fromSource = String.format("netty4:tcp://%s:%d?clientMode=true&textline=true&receiveBufferSize=64000&decoderMaxLineLength=64000",sourceIp,sourcePort);
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        from(fromSource)
        .to("metrics:counter:incomingCounter");


    };
}
```

The route works nearly fine but consumes more and more heap-space (around 2MB every second, where there are messages served with a frequency of around 20-30Hz) until java throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Without any route no memory-leak was registered, as i can focus the problem to the netty-route

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution myself by debugging the code.
I forgot to set property **sync=false** in netty4-camel endpoint as i don't want to process message and send an answer back to the server after processing, just consuming - while sync=true (default settings) buffers all incoming data for later response which caused my "memory-leak".
The behavior of "sync" was not totally clear from the netty4-camel documentation (http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html) - i'll suggest an improvement of the documentation (will write a mail with a proposal) to make the usage a little more clearly.

Maybe this helps someone another having a similar problem.

Best